# JPA mapping: “QuerySyntaxException: FooBar is not mapped…”

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I'm getting `FooBar is not mapped` exception, even though I have placed all the necessary annotations:

The Entity annotation in the model class:

**model/FooBar.java***

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "ORDERS")
public class FooBar {}
```

The Repository, PersistenceContext and Transactioinal in DAO. Also, I referenced it by the name of the class, "FooBar", correctly

**db/FooBarDao.java**

```
@Repository
public class OrderDAO {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Transactional
    public List<FooBar> getFooBars() {
        return em.createQuery(
                "select fb from FooBar fb",
                FooBar.class
        ).getResultList();
    }
}
```

Here is the configuration to get it all working:

**conf/DbConfig.java**

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"project.db"})
public class DbConfig {

    @Autowired
    public Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        System.out.println("Configuring database!!!!!!!!");
        DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:myjdbc");

        new JdbcTemplate(ds)
                .update(FileUtil.readFile2("./src/main/java/project/db/sql/initialize.sql"));

        return ds;
    }


    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {

        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
        factory.setPackagesToScan("model");
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();

        return factory.getObject();
    }

    private Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect",
                "org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "true");

        return properties;
    }

}
```

Comment: `select fb from FooBar o` .... and what is "fb" when you have set the alias for `FooBar` in this query to be `o`???

Comment: Initially it was an order processing system. I forgot to switch the o to fb when making the question. My bad. Edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not finding the mapping, even though I have set the annotations correctly, and referenced the class correctly. So the problem is most likely with scanning for the model class.

My project structure is `/src/main/java/project/`...

So, scanning for `model`:

`factory.setPackagesToScan("model");`

Will not find any beans. Instead, I need to do

`factory.setPackagesToScan("project.model");`

Which fixes the problem.